# command prompt error messges for md 'prn', 'con', and 'nul'

Tags: windows, command-prompt

Im curious about the error messages the command prompt returns for the following commands:

```
C:\>md prn
The directory name is invalid.

C:\>md con
The directory name is invalid.

C:\>md nul

C:\>cd nul
The parameter is incorrect.
```

Why doesn't "md nul" return an error?

*Edit* - I understand why this is wrong, what with reserved words and such. I was wondering specifically about the lack of an error message on 'md nul'

Comment: I think it's because `nul` is a valid output destination, and therefore is literally swallowing the output for `md`.

Comment: This sounds likely, I wonder if there is any documentation on this behavior somewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably because `CreateDirectory(_T("NUL"), NULL)` returns `1` even though it fails to create a directory.

Answer (score 1):

> In Windows and DOS, some words might also be **reserved** and can **not** be used as filenames.
>  For example, **DOS Device file**:
>
> CON, PRN, AUX, CLOCK$, NUL COM0, COM1,
>   COM2, COM3, COM4, COM5, COM6, COM7,
>   COM8, COM9 LPT0, LPT1, LPT2, LPT3,
>   LPT4, LPT5, LPT6, LPT7, LPT8, and
>   LPT9.

Source [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filename#Reserved_characters_and_words)

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.

Answer (score 0):

'nul' is a null-device, similar to `/dev/null` under Linux. It seems that `MD` (make dir) accepts this name, but ignores any errors about it.

Comment: That's exactly what he said.  He's asking why.